# ASP.NET MVC Design Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

1. Whats the difference between Model and ViewModel? I should use both of them or I better skip one of them? who grabs the data from the database?
2. I wonder whats the best/right way to take my data from the database.

One option is to have a DAL (Data Access Layer) and instantiate it in every controller,
fill with it the viewmodels like:

```
var viewmodel = Dal.GetArticles();
```

Another option is to let the model itself grab the information from the Database:

```
var model = new ArticlesModel();
model.GetArticles();

public void GetArticles()
{
var context = new DbContext();
_articles = context.Articles
}
```

Another similar option is to have a static DAL so you can access it inside every model,
so each model will have a method to grab the data using the static DAL class (Which contain a DbContext class inside to access the Database)

```
public void GetArticles()
{
_articles = DAL.GetArticles();
}
```

So the general question is if the model itself needs to grab the data from the database or the controller itself can have access to the DAL.

Comment: In MVC the model designed to give the data structure of the object, no to contain data. for this you may use the controller.

Comment: Can you explain or give a simple example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While someone is writing a more useful answer, I will quickly address your points.

**`Model` is the *data* you want to display.**

More often than not, you will want to use object relational mapping so most of your business object classes correspond to database tables and you don't have to manually construct queries.

There are plenty of ORM solutions available, including Entity Framework, NHibernate and (now dying) LINQ to SQL.

There is also an awesome micro-ORM called [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) which you may like if bigger frameworks feel unneccessarily bloated for your solution.

Make sure you learn about the differences between them.

**DAL is more idiomatic in .NET than [classes that “know” how to load themselves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern).**

(Although in practice your solution will very likely be a mixture of both approaches—the key is, as usual, to keep the balance.)

My advice is to try keeping your models [plain old CLR objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) as long as your ORM allows it and as long as this doesn't add extra level of complexity to the calling code.

These objects, whenever possible (and sensible—there are exceptions for any rule!),   should not be tied to a particular database or ORM implementation.

Migrating your code to another ORM, if needed, will be just a matter of rewriting data access layer.
You should understand, however, that this is **not** the main reason to separate DAL.

It is highly unlikely you'll want to change an ORM in the middle of the project, unless your initial choice was really unfit for the purpose or you suddenly gained a traction of 100,000 of users and your ORM can't handle it. **Optimizing for this in the beginning is downright stupid because it distracts you from creating a great product capable of attracting even a fraction of hits you're optimizing for.** (Disclaimer: I've walked this path before.)

Rather, the benefit of DAL is that you **database access becomes always explicit and constrained to certain places where you want it to happen.** For example, a view that received a model object to display will not be tempted to load something from the database, because in fact it is the job of controller to do so.

It's also generally good to separate things like business logic, presentation logic and database logic. Too often it results in better, less bug-ridden code. Also: you are likely to find it difficult to unit-test any code that relies on objects being loaded from the database. On the other hand, creating a “fake” in-memory data access layer is trivial with LINQ.

Please keep in mind that again, **there are exceptions to this rule**, like lazy properties generated by many ORMs that will load the associated objects on the go—even if called within a view. So what matters is you should make an informed decision when to allow data  access and why. Syntaxic sugar might be useful but if your team has no idea about performance implications of loading 20,000 objects from ORM, it will become a problem.

Before using any ORM, [learn how it works under the hood](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

Choosing between Active Record-style objects and a DAL is mostly a matter of taste, common idioms in .NET, team habits and the possibility that DAL might eventually have to get replaced.

**Finally, `ViewModel`s are a different kind of beast.**

Try to think of them like this:

1. You shouldn't have any logic in views that is more sophisticated than an `if-then-else`.
2. However, there often *is* some sophisticated logic in *showing* things.
   Think pagination, sorting, combining different models in one view, understanding UI state.

These are the kinds of thing a view model could handle.
In simple cases, it just combines several different models into one “view-model”:

```
class AddOrderViewModel {
    // So the user knows what is already ordered
    public IEnumerable<Order> PreviousOrders { get; set; }
    // Object being added (keeping a reference in case of validation errors)
    public Order CurrentOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Models are *just data*, controllers combine the data and introduce some logic to describe *data to be shown* in view models, and views just render view models.

View model also serves as a kind of documentation. They answer two questions:

1. **What data can I use in a view?**
2. **What data should I prepare in controller?**

Instead of passing objects into `ViewData` and remembering their names and types, use [generic views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079035/using-asp-net-mvc-with-generic-views) and put stuff in `ViewModel`'s properties, which are statically typed and available with IntelliSense.

Also, you'll likely find it useful to create `ViewModel` hierarchies (but don't take it to extremes!). For example, if your site-wide navigation changes from breadcrumbs to something else, it's cool to just replace a property on *base view model*, a *partial view* to display it and *the logic to construct it* in the *base controller*. Keep it sensible.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the really detailed answer!
I will keep reading the links in the answer and reading your answer again to fully understand it.

Answer (score 2):

A model represents the structure you like your data in and is not concerned about the view which may consume it. A model's intend is purely that of representing the structure.

A model may contain properties irrelevant to the view consuming it.

A view-model is designed with the view in mind. A view-model is intended for a 1-to-1 relationship to a view. A view-model only contains the basic fields and properties the view it is intended for requires.

In general you would have your controller contact a repository (In your example your DAL) obtaining the data and then populating either a model or view-model with the results, sending it down to the view.

Comment: Thanks mate! you helped me understand the order of all these things.
Just one more thing to ask - Its not a bit wrong that the controller will grab the data from the DAL, as the data itself should be transparent to the controller?

I might be wrong, But I am just asking to learn more from your reply.

Comment: In MVC that is the basic intention of the controller. The controller is the manager of things in the UI layer. On a very basic level, on the way down the controller contacts repositories, uses data to build a model and sends it to the view. On the way up, the action in the controller can again validate the model state, then call the repository, passing the posted data. That is the basic design to build on top of but the basic idea should not change.

Answer (score 1):

**Model (Domain Model)**: is the heart of the application, representing the biggest and most important business asset because it captures all the complex business entities, their relationships and their functionality.

**ViewModel**: Sitting atop the Model is the ViewModel:The two primary goals of the ViewModel are 
1. to make the Model easily consumable by the View and
2. to separate and encapsulate the Model from the View.

Eg.

Model:

```
public class Product
{
...............
}

public class Category
{
...........
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public ProductViewModel(List<Product> products, List<Category> categories)
        {
            this.Products = products;
            this.Categories = categories;
        }

        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    }
```